# Hbase scan error with happybase

Tags: hbase

When I use happybase to scan hbase,

```
In [4]: connection = happybase.Connection('192.168.31.34', 
protocol="compact")

In [5]: table = connection.table('flash_news')

In [6]: for key,data in table.scan():
   ...:     print(key, data)
```

connection is right, but scan shows error like below, I don't know why this happen, but i think something wrong with thrift:

```
thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.pyx in 
thriftpy.transport.buffered.cybuffered.TCyBufferedTransport.read 
(thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.c:1625)()

thriftpy/transport/cybase.pyx in 
thriftpy.transport.cybase.CyTransportBase.get_string 
(thriftpy/transport/cybase.c:2294)()

thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.pyx in 
thriftpy.transport.buffered.cybuffered.TCyBufferedTransport.c_read 
(thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.c:1881)()

thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.pyx in 

thriftpy.transport.buffered.cybuffered.TCyBufferedTransport.read_trans 
(thriftpy/transport/buffered/cybuffered.c:1948)()

thriftpy/transport/cybase.pyx in 
thriftpy.transport.cybase.TCyBuffer.read_trans 
(thriftpy/transport/cybase.c:1472)()

/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/news/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/thriftpy/transport/socket.pyc in read(self, sz)
        123         if len(buff) == 0:
        124             raise 
    TTransportException(type=TTransportException.END_OF_FILE,
    --> 125                                       message='TSocket read 
    0 bytes')
        126         return buff
        127

    TTransportException: TTransportException(message='TSocket read 0 bytes', type=4)
```

and my `happybase` version is `1.1.0`, Hbase is `2.1.0`, anyone can give me   some advice.

Comment: I am able to recreate the same error if I add the protocol="compact" parameter, as you did. However without it everything works well. Any reason you need it? Maybe try removing it?

Comment: @VS_FF, remove compact then everything is ok, thanks. In fact, I didn't use protocal from the start, but it also has something the matter.  Whaterver, thanks a lot.